# Why does Gwen need to learn to use a hand gun?

Tags: torchwood

In episode 3 of season 1 of Torchwood, Jack is seen teaching Gwen to fire a gun.

> You need to learn to use these.  I hope you never need to.

She's a former police officer.  Wouldn't she already have been trained in the use of a hand gun as part of her police training?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Police in Great Britain don't necessarily use firearms. She may have never been officially trained in their use.

Wikipedia: [Use of Firearms in the United Kingdoms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Police_use_of_firearms_in_the_United_Kingdom).

> The United Kingdom is made up of four constituent countries: England, Scotland, Wales (which make up Great Britain) and Northern Ireland. In Northern Ireland, all police officers carry firearms. **In the rest of the United Kingdom, police officers do not carry firearms, except in special circumstances.** This originates from the formation of the Metropolitan Police Service in the 19th century, when police were not armed, partly to counter public fears and objections over armed enforcers as this had been previously seen due to the British Army maintaining order when needed. The arming of police in Great Britain is a perennial topic of debate.

Comment: Should make that "Police in Great Britain" or "Police in Wales"

Comment: Indeed, to quote Gwen Copper in Miracle Day "I'm Welsh"